# Getting Coded UI exception "Failed To Perform Action On Blocked Control" on a url links with same relative path

Tags: c#, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I'm getting this exception on URL links on my page with the same relative paths.  It works fine for other pages where links might have different relative path.
For example I have a situation where i have :

Link 1

Link 2

Link 3

Link 4

Now all of these links text are different but the relative paths are the same. I iterated and get all 4 links.  I click on the first one and the test is fine. When i go to click on the 2 link it seems to lose focus and tries to click on what it seems link 1 this then bombs which causes this blocking exception.

This is what i've tried below but it seems to be now breaking on Link 3.

```
    Point point1 = myfinalLinks2Verify.GetClickablePoint();                                                             
                 Mouse.Hover(myfinalLinks2Verify, point1);
                 Mouse.Click(myfinalLinks2Verify, point1);
```

Now when i run the code and its running The error seems to happen where the i instantiated point1.  Why is it breaking there and is there either a way around this or do i have to set focus to my control to fix this before hovering or clicking on it?

Answer (score 0):

The blocking issue was due to a line of code that was not hit for the dialogue message box.  After stepping and debugging it i saw that i was skipping the code to click an open button on the dialogue box thus causing it to go to the next link, and since this dialogue box was already opened it was causing the blocking issue. 
I guess its better to step through then assume. I guess this wrong assumption of my part caused me to miss it since it was iterating through the other links.

I hope this helps someone. Thanks